# Dialog Fragment java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am calling a list inside a dialog fragment which is loaded from a custom adapter.

loading my fragment

```
ProfileListViewHolder.imageButtonMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ProfileDialog ProfileDialogFragment = new ProfileDialog();

            ProfileDialogFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentManager =((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            fragmentManager.replace(R.id.drawer_layout,ProfileDialogFragment) .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });
```

and this is my Dialog that i am using

```
public class ProfileDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

private Context context;

public View   profileView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (profileView == null) {
           profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_dialog, container,false);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) profileView .getParent()).removeView(profileView );
    }

    ListView   profileListView = (ListView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.lstvSelectedProfile);


    return profileListView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //addInnerFragment();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    return dialog;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `((ViewGroup) profileView.getParent()).removeView(profileView )`?

Comment: @azizbekian: i assumed this may help me remove the parent that may be troubling here

Comment: If you want to use `ProfileDialog` as a dialog, you need to use it's `show()` method, rather than the transaction you're using there.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the profileListView instead of profileView. change the code like this ,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_dialog, container, false);
        ListView profileListView = (ListView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.lstvSelectedProfile);
        return profileView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_dialog, container,false);

  ListView profileListView = (ListView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.lstvSelectedProfile);

  return profileView;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than Krish's answer?